# Submit not working for Adaptive Card in Teams posted by Azure Bot

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have an Adaptive Card posted to Teams from an Azure Bot requesting the user to enter values for the fields displayed. When the user hits the Submit button, nothing happens. Yet in WebChat or Adaptive Card Designer, it works perfectly. I even use to work when I use to post the Adaptive Card from a Logic App to Teams.

Here's the Adaptive Card:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "medium",
            "weight": "bolder",
            "text": "Start VM"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Enter the details of the Virtual Machine to restart",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "VM Name",
                            "wrap": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "placeholder": "e.g. servername",
                            "id": "vmName"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "VM Resource Group",
                            "wrap": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "placeholder": "e.g. resourcegroup",
                            "id": "vmResourceGroup"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Username",
                            "wrap": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "placeholder": "e.g. joe.bloggs@contoso.com",
                            "id": "username"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "ServiceNow SysID for Change Record",
                            "wrap": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "placeholder": "e.g. 11cef313db4ce0d012d9147a3a961909",
                            "id": "sysId"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [  
        {  
            "type": "Action.Submit",  
            "title": "Submit"
        }  
    ]
}
```

The C# Code in the Azure Bot the constructs the Adaptive Card is the following:

```
private Attachment CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment()
{
    var cardResourcePath = "EchoBot.Cards.startVMCard.json";

    using (var stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(cardResourcePath))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var adaptiveCard = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return new Attachment()
            {
                ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCard),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The Code for the Azure Bot that sends the Adaptive Card is the following:

```
var startVMCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(startVMCard);
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please try posting your Adaptive card JSON using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio#card-editor) and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks @Dev. Yes I tried posting the Adaptive Card using App studio and it worked. Why it's not working when it's posted by the Bot, I don't know :(

Comment: Oh, that's weird @mrptsai. I am not aware of any limitation/issue. Being said that let me see what i can dig further on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

It appears that Teams is using Skype Framework 3.0 and doesn't have the postBack method. An Adaptive Card submit does not contain `postBack` in the ChannelData. An Adaptive Card submit using the Framework Emulator contains `postBack` in the ChannelData.

I added the following code to cater for this issue:

```
var channelData = JObject.Parse(turnContext.Activity.ChannelData.ToString());
JObject activity = JObject.Parse(turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString());

if (channelData.ContainsKey("postBack") || activity.HasValues == true)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I see a similar problem where I am testing the sample app from the bot builder SDK sample (54. TeamsTaskModule) , it works fine on Teams Desktop App, but clicking on adaptive card button (Adaptive Card) is not working on the Microsoft Teams Web app, any idea, why?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thanks for reaching us.

I have gone through and tested your adaptive card json and method that you implemented.

Able to get the values in "adaptivecards.io/designer",
[image]

Also, i have tried in Microsoft Teams too, able to get the values in code "turnContext"
[image]

[image]

So, in Submit button action, you have to implement your code to display the values in Bot.

Please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference), you will get complete knowledge on cards and how to implement the cards.

Comment: Thanks, Rama-MSFT I really appreciate your time in trying to resolve this.

I too have tried what you did and had the same success, but when I try interacting with the Bot via Teams, it just doesn't work.

Using vscode and the Bot Framework Emulator, I can step through the code, see the response perfectly, but not in Teams, So weird.

I'll keep testing and tweaking and let you know what I find.

Thanks again.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: I found the issue.  I haven’t had a chance to post the details.  Basically, Teams uses Skype framework 3.0 and doesn’t appear to have the post back function. I had to change the code after receiving the values from the Adaptive Card. I’ll post solution when I can.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OK - Trying to debug this mystery. In Visual Studio I can view the Streaming log from the Bot in Azure.

When testing the Bot via the Bot Framework Emulator connected to the Bot remotely it works perfectly. I see the following after clicking the submit button in the logs:

```
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:39.456 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://startvmbot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages application/json 678
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:39.456 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executing endpoint 'StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot)'
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:39.456 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Route matched with {action = "Post", controller = "Bot"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task PostAsync() on controller StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController (startvmbot).
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:39.456 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing action method StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot) - Validation state: Valid
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:39.460 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter: Received an incoming activity.  ActivityId: e920c600-44e9-11eb-aa2c-f5a359761b0e
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:39.657 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter: Sending activity.  ReplyToId: e920c600-44e9-11eb-aa2c-f5a359761b0e
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:39.658 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter: GetTokenAsync: Acquired token using ADAL in 0.
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:40.128 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action method StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EmptyResult in 671.7897ms.
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:40.128 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot) in 672.1344ms
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:40.128 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executed endpoint 'StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot)'
Application:2020-12-23 06:41:40.129 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 673.416ms 200
```

This is the result in Bot Framework Emulator
[image: Bot Emulator]

When testing the Bot via Teams it doesn't work. I see the following after clicking the submit button in the logs:

```
Application:2020-12-23 06:39:56.705 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://startvmbot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages application/json; charset=utf-8 1136
Application:2020-12-23 06:39:56.705 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executing endpoint 'StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot)'
Application:2020-12-23 06:39:56.705 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Route matched with {action = "Post", controller = "Bot"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task PostAsync() on controller StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController (startvmbot).
Application:2020-12-23 06:39:56.705 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing action method StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot) - Validation state: Valid
Application:2020-12-23 06:39:56.707 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter: Received an incoming activity.  ActivityId: f:6238602817490478374
Application:2020-12-23 06:39:56.708 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action method StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EmptyResult in 2.2726ms.
Application:2020-12-23 06:39:56.708 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot) in 2.5461ms
Application:2020-12-23 06:39:56.708 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executed endpoint 'StartVMBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (startvmbot)'
Application:2020-12-23 06:39:56.708 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished in 3.6941ms 200
```

This is the result in Teams:
[image: Teams]

I'll keep looking, but if anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate them!